# How to make Tkinter use any given Tcl interpreter, other that system wide Tcl interpreter

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a legacy Tcl based application and I am planning to write a python wrapper for the same. My Tcl legacy application ships with its own Tcl interpreter. It doesn't use the interpreter provided by the system.

I am planning to use Tkinter.Tcl() to hook with the Tcl interpreter and execute Tcl instruction using eval.

But Python's Tkinter is invoking default Tcl interpreter installed on the system. How to instruct Tkinter to use Tcl interpreter shipped  with my legacy application ???

PS: I don't have root privilege on the system, but I am OK with rebuilding Python or Tcl or both in my local workspace.

Comment: Which OS platform(s) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

All linkage with Tk libraries happens through Python's `_tkinter.so` C extension module.  You *could* try to just build it, linked with your libraries but that is only guaranteed to work if `_tkinter.so` is built with the same options as the system Python's in use on all of your users' systems.  The safest and surest way is to build your own Python linked with your Tcl/Tk and ship it as part of your application.  It can be a little bit tricky to get Python to link with Tcl/Tk in a non-standard location; it may just be easiest to modify the `detect_tkinter` method in Python's top-level [`setup.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/setup.py) to look in the desired locations for your `include` and `lib` files.  (`setup.py` is what controls the building of the Python standard library modules, including `_tkinter.so`.)

Comment: I hope there should be some easier or direct way.

Comment: Python embeds Tcl/Tk using some pretty low-level C APIs. Bad things can happen if the versions of Tcl and Tk that Python was built with do not match the versions it later executes with.  You just can't be sure that it will work.

Comment: Also, it's not at all unusual to include a builtin Python with an application.  If you're going to ship your own Tcl, why not your own Python, too?

Comment: I am ok with shipping python along the application but how will I make sure that python will point to the Tcl shipped with the application.

Comment: It might be possible to statically link Tcl and Tk with Python.  Otherwise, you should be able to define your shipping directory structure and either add `-rpath` options to the `_tkinter` link step or ensure that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gets set at run time to include the location of your Tcl and Tk libraries.